# Deploying react app using Netlify gives error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, netlify

I am trying to deploy a react app using Netlify, but I keep getting this error, and I do not know why.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'axios' in '/opt/build/repo/src'

When I use npm start to run the app from my device, the app works as expected, and axios has no errors. Why can axios not be found when I try to deploy it, even though it works on my device?

Answer (score 0):

Check if axios is included in your dependencies (`package.json`) and not installed globally or as a dev dependency. (via `npm install -g` or `npm install -D`). If it isn't, prompt `npm i axios` without the `-g`/`-D` flag